# Strange Clang behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, llvm, clang

Have a look at this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(int(*f)()) {
    std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::string(*f)()) {
    std::string s = f();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto bar = [] () -> std::string {
        return std::string("bla");
    };

    foo(bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11
```

leads to:

```
bla
```

like it should do. Compiling it with

```
clang++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

leads to:

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./test
```

And Compiling it with

```
clang++ -o test test.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=stdlibc++
```

leads also to:

```
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./test
```

Clang/GCC Versions:

```
clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

gcc version 4.7.2 (Gentoo 4.7.2-r1 p1.5, pie-0.5.5)
```

Anyone any suggestions what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say this is a bug in Clang

Comment: FYI, more information on [ud2 and clang](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26309300/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely a bug in clang 3.2. I can't reproduce the crash with clang trunk.

Comment: Affirmative. Trunk seems to work fine. So it probably should be fixed in clang 3.3.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is a bug in Clang++. I can reproduce it with CLang 3.2 in i386-pc-linux-gnu.

And now some random analysis...

I've found that the bug is in the conversion from labmda to pointer-to-function: the compiler creates a kind of *thunk* with the appropriate signature that calls the lambda, but it has the instruction `ud2` instead of `ret`.

The instruction `ud2`, as you all probably know, is an instruction that explicitly raises the "Invalid Opcode" exception. That is, an instruction intentionally left undefined.

Take a look at the disassemble: this is the thunk function:

```
main::$_0::__invoke():
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        movl    %ecx, 4(%esp)
        calll   main::$_0::operator()() const ; this calls to the real lambda
        subl    $4, %esp
        ud2   ; <<<-- What the...!!!
```

So a minimal example of the bug will be simply:

```
int main() {
    std::string(*f)() = [] () -> std::string {
        return "bla";
    };
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Curiously enough, the bug doesn't happen if the return type is a simple type, such as `int`. Then the generated *thunk* is:

```
main::$_0::__invoke():
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $8, %esp
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        calll   main::$_0::operator()() const
        addl    $8, %esp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

I suspect that the problem is in the forwarding of the return value. If it fits in a register, such as `eax` all goes well. But if it is a big struct, such as `std::string` it is returned in the stack, the compiler is confused and emits the `ud2` in desperation.