# What's the point of adding ud2 after writing to [ds:0x0]?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86

I was experimenting with GCC, trying to convince it to assume that certain portions of code are unreachable so as to take opportunity to optimize. One of my experiments gave me somewhat strange code. Here's the source:

```
#include <iostream>

#define UNREACHABLE {char* null=0; *null=0; return {};}

double test(double x)
{
    if(x==-1) return -1;
    else if(x==1) return 1;
    UNREACHABLE;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number. Only +/- 1 is supported, otherwise I dunno what'll happen: ";
    double x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Here's what I got: " << test(x) << "\n";
}
```

Here's how I compiled it:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -O3 -march=native -S -masm=intel -Wall -Wextra
```

And the code of `test` function looks like this:

```
_Z4testd:
.LFB1397:
        .cfi_startproc
        fld     QWORD PTR [esp+4]
        fld1
        fchs
        fld     st(0)
        fxch    st(2)
        fucomi  st, st(2)
        fstp    st(2)
        jp      .L10
        je      .L11
        fstp    st(0)
        jmp     .L7
.L10:
        fstp    st(0)
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L7:
        fld1
        fld     st(0)
        fxch    st(2)
        fucomip st, st(2)
        fstp    st(1)
        jp      .L12
        je      .L6
        fstp    st(0)
        jmp     .L8
.L12:
        fstp    st(0)
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L8:
        mov     BYTE PTR ds:0, 0
        ud2         // This is redundant, isn't it?..
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L11:
        fstp    st(1)
.L6:
        rep; ret
```

What makes me wonder here is the code at `.L8`. Namely, it already writes to zero address, which guarantees segmentation fault unless `ds` has some non-default selector. So why the additional `ud2`? Isn't writing to zero address already guaranteed crash? Or does GCC not believe that `ds` has default selector and tries to make a sure-fire crash?

Comment: potentially writing to zero address migh work. For some hardware it is as good address as any other. Sure, most OS make sure that it is never a valid address for given process, but it is better to make sure ourselves, right? BTW,

Comment: A write to [ds:0] may not result in a segmentation fault in every OS. Thus the *ud2*.

Comment: [Undefined behavior leads to GCC emitting an UD2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310534/507028)

Comment: @MargaretBloom but I was compiling for a particular OS, namely Linux x86!

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot the hardware here is exactly x86, it can't be any other.

Comment: @Neitsa yeah, I'm familiar with that Q&A. This question is "_why ud2 in addition to mov dword[ds:0],0_", not just "_why ud2_".

Comment: @Ruslan I went googling for it and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309300/c-code-with-undefined-results-compiler-generates-invalid-code-with-o3). Haven't you seen this all already?

Comment: @Ruslan I believe the *ud2* is there  because null deferencing is UB and so the memory access can be optimized out, but the *ud2* would remain. There is an example in [this](http://project1439.rssing.com/chan-6400099/all_p1.html) page where the memory access is optimized out, search for "It is allowed to do this because calling a null pointer is undefined, which permits it to assume that set() must be called before call()".

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, right, the memory access can be optimized out, but it wasn't. That's the core of my question: why, despite the memory access instruction is emitted, the ud2 is still emitted too.

Comment: @Ruslan The only thing that comes in my mind is this: Sometimes you need to access the address 0x0, e.g. during boot, or in a kernel module that map a page there. This would be achieved by deferencing a null pointer and anything would work like a charm. But for the C standard that is UB and so the compiler kindly remind you of that with an #UD exception, forcing you to write compliant code.

Comment: @MargaretBloom hmm, this sounds plausible. Why not add this as an answer?

Comment: @Ruslan mmm, It should be a little bit more elaborate. Anyway, citing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759845/why-is-address-zero-used-for-the-null-pointer) answer, It makes clear that a *null pointer* is not tied to a *null address*, so deferencing a null pointer has nothing to do with accessing the address 0 (which is a valid operation in C), rather it is an inherently wrong thing to do. Interesting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, your code is writing to address zero (NULL) which in itself is defined to be "undefined behaviour". Since undefined behaviour covers anything, and most importantly for this case, "that it does what you may imagine that it would do" (in other words, writes to address zero rather than crashing). The compiler then decides to TELL you that by adding an `UD2` instruction. It's also possible that it is to protect against continuing from a signal handler with further undefined behaviour.

Yes, most machines, under most circumstances, will crash for `NULL` accesses. But it's not 100% guaranteed, and as I said above, one can catch segfault in a signal handler, and then try to continue - it's really not a good idea to actually continue after trying to write to `NULL`, so the compiler adds `UD2` to ensure you don't go on... It uses 2 bytes more of memory, beyond that I don't see what harm it does [after all, it's undefined what happens - if the compiler wished to do so, it could email random pictures from your filesystem to the Queen of England... I think UD2 is a better choice...]

It is interesting to spot that LLVM does this by itself - I have no special detection of `NIL` pointer access, but my pascal compiler compiles this:

```
program p;

var
   ptr : ^integer;

begin
   ptr := NIL;
   ptr^ := 42;
end.
```

into:

```
0000000000400880 <__PascalMain>:
  400880:   55                      push   %rbp
  400881:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400884:   48 c7 05 19 18 20 00    movq   $0x0,0x201819(%rip)        # 6020a8 <ptr>
  40088b:   00 00 00 00 
  40088f:   0f 0b                   ud2
```

I'm still trying to figure out where in LLVM this happens and try to understand the purpose of the UD2 instruction itself.

I think the answer is here, in llvm/lib/Transforms/Utils/Local.cpp

```
void llvm::changeToUnreachable(Instruction *I, bool UseLLVMTrap) {
  BasicBlock *BB = I->getParent();
  // Loop over all of the successors, removing BB's entry from any PHI
  // nodes.
  for (succ_iterator SI = succ_begin(BB), SE = succ_end(BB); SI != SE; ++SI)
    (*SI)->removePredecessor(BB);

  // Insert a call to llvm.trap right before this.  This turns the undefined
  // behavior into a hard fail instead of falling through into random code.
  if (UseLLVMTrap) {
    Function *TrapFn =
      Intrinsic::getDeclaration(BB->getParent()->getParent(), Intrinsic::trap);
    CallInst *CallTrap = CallInst::Create(TrapFn, "", I);
    CallTrap->setDebugLoc(I->getDebugLoc());
  }
  new UnreachableInst(I->getContext(), I);

  // All instructions after this are dead.
  BasicBlock::iterator BBI = I->getIterator(), BBE = BB->end();
  while (BBI != BBE) {
    if (!BBI->use_empty())
      BBI->replaceAllUsesWith(UndefValue::get(BBI->getType()));
    BB->getInstList().erase(BBI++);
  }
}
```

In particular the comment in the middle, where it says "instead of falling through to the into random code". In your code there is no code following the NULL access, but imagine this:

```
void func()
{
    if (answer == 42)
    {
     #if DEBUG
         // Intentionally crash to avoid formatting hard disk for now

         char *ptr = NULL;
         ptr = 0;
    #endif
         // Format hard disk. 
         ... some code to format hard disk ... 
    }
    printf("We haven't found the answer yet\n");
    ... 
}
```

So, this SHOULD crash, but if it doesn't the compiler will ensure that you do not continue after it... It makes UB crashes a little more obvious (and in this case prevents the hard disk from being formatted...)

I was trying to find out when this was introduced, but the function itself originates in 2007, but it's not used for exactly this purpose at the time, which makes it really hard to figure out why it is used this way.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux it's possible to allocate a zero address with `mmap`, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63790813/673852), and use the resulting pointer for reading and writing. So writing to `[ds:0]` doesn't guarantee crash, even with the default selector in `ds`.