# allocating address zero on Linux with mmap fails

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I am writing a static program loader for Linux, I am reading ELF program headers and mapping the segments to the memory.

I have come across an executable which assumes that the virtual address of its first segment is at 0. My memory mapping fails, I get error allocating virtual page at address `0`.

I wonder if it is possible to allocate at all memory at address `0` for the user-space.

See this example code:

```
/*mmaptests.c*/
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    void* p = mmap(0, sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_FIXED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    printf("mmap result %p (errno %s)\n",p,strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with:

```
gcc mmaptests.c
```

This is what it returns :

```
$./a.out
mmap result 0xffffffffffffffff (errno Operation not permitted)
```

I will be happy for any insights.

Thanks
B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux will only let you `mmap` the 0-th page if you have privileges, or on a system with the sysctl setting `vm.mmap_min_addr = 0` (instead of the default 65536).

```
gcc mmaptests.c && sudo ./a.out
```

should get you:

```
mmap result (nil) (errno Success)
```

---

According to https://wiki.debian.org/mmap_min_addr, WINE for 16-bit Windows applications needs `vm.mmap_min_addr = 0`, and so do old versions of QEMU to run as non-root.  Most distros won't do that even in the installers for those packages, though, because making NULL-deref fail noisily by faulting is *very* desirable.  (64 KiB also covers small array indexes from a base of 0.)

You can check your current setting with `cat /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr`, or to format as hex, `printf '%#x\n' $(cat /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr)`

Comment: Is this a kernel limitation?

Comment: I made a test to find out what is the lowest address I can allocate with mmap, I see it is 0x10000

Comment: @BenHirschberg It appears to be a kernel policy designed to protect against userspace exploiting NULL-dereference bugs in kernel code/modules: https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/much-ado-about-null%3a-exploiting-a-kernel-null-dereference-v2

Comment: @BenHirschberg It's a security feature. The lower bound is initially the greater of `CONFIG_DEFAULT_MMAP_MIN_ADDR` and `CONFIG_LSM_MMAP_MIN_ADDR` kernel config parameters, and can be set to any value greater than or equal to `CONFIG_LSM_MMAP_MIN_ADDR` by `sysctl vm.mmap_min_addr NEW_MIN_ADDR`.

Comment: @BenHirschberg Yes. According to the article I've linked in my 1st comment, that `0x10000` should match with what you'd get with `printf '%#x\n' $(cat /proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr)`.

Comment: @BenHirschberg See `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` in `man 7 capabilities`.

Comment: Allocating mem on zero can be used for fun. For example after allocating a page page with rwx and calling nil func I got `[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x1000 pc=0x1000]`. seems like pc jumped to 0 so it segved after hitting the end of that page. https://gist.github.com/quant61/419fc25cbbe462749d802511d0bff112

Comment: @quant2016 That's interesting. Didn't know zeros acted as nop instructions on x86-64. Doesn't seem to be documented either, but I did try your example and I'm also getting a fault on the second page.

Comment: 0 is *not* a noop on x86_64 -- it's an `ADD Eb,Gb` instruction -- byte add with operands determined by a following mod r/m byte.  If that byte is also 0 then the destination is `AL` and the source is `byte ptr [RAX]`  --  `add (%rax), %al` in att syntax.

Comment: Nice. That should explain why it gets through the first page. Rax is probably zero after the successful `mmap(NULL,4096,...,MAP_FIXED,...)`, so it ends up adding zeros to zero call until a MAP_ERROR segfault. Thank you for the explanation, @ChrisDodd.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Correction, `00 00` is x86 machine code for a memory *destination* `add [rax], al`.  So the memory needs to be writeable, and non-zero data in memory doesn't modify the low byte of the "pointer" in RAX (although that couldn't change what page was being accessed even if you were repeating `add al, [rax]` `02 00` instead.)  So yes, with a pointer to writeable memory in RAX, `00 00` bytes can execute without faulting, unfortunately.  (RISC-V chose `00 00` to be "unimplemented" so it faults, so it definitely can't work as a NOP-sled; on some earlier RISCs `00 00 00 00` is a nop)